# javascript: extensive use of 'this' in reusable d3js charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, this

In the source code for a reusable d3 library (code found here: https://github.com/bugzu/reD3/blob/master/src/area.js ) nearly every line contains a reference to `this`.  Website homepage: http://bugzu.github.io/reD3/#/

Example:

```
(function(global) {

    global.reD3 = global.reD3 || {};

    function Area(element, options) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = options;
        this.init();
    }

    Area.prototype = {

        init: function() {
            var options = this.options,
            width = options.width || 960,
            height = options.height || 500,
            oMargin = options.margin;

            var margin = {
                top: 20,
                right: 30,
                bottom: 30,
                left: 40
            },

            margin = reD3.util.mixin(margin, oMargin);

            width = this.width = width - margin.left - margin.right;
            height = this.height = height - margin.top - margin.bottom;
            var xValue = this.xValue = options.xValue || 'date';
            var yValue = this.yValue = options.yValue || 'value';
```

What is the purpose of this being used so frequently?  What are the advantages/disadv of a technique like this for reusable (chart) components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Area is a class (you can tell by the use of 'this' in the constructor function, and calls to it will use the `new` keyword), the use of `this` modifies the object rather than a local or global variable.  Regardless of whether a library is for charts or anything else, using `this` encourages encapsulation, although it's admittedly much less obvious than in other languages with classes.